# Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.TR4Android:AppCompat-Extension-Library:v0.4.0

Tags: android

I according to github's steps,but got

> failed to resolve:com.github.TR4Android:AppCompat-Extension-Library:v0.4.0 
>   error.

This is my gradle content.

```
repositories {

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.TR4Android:AppCompat-Extension-Library:v0.4.0'
}
```